# Is it better to keep JSON data in stringformat in viewstate or List<T>

Tags: asp.net, json, aspxgridview

I want to improve performance of web application. I used to put a List in viewstate to bind it to Gridview. Now i am thinking that call that list from REST service in JSON. SO i want to know is it better to put JSON data in string format in viewstate or List?
Which consumes more space?

Answer (score 0):

If space if you're primary concern JSON will be better, but if you are looking at performance of an ASP site and you are storing lots of data in viewstate you will rapidly run into all sorts of problems.

Could the data not be put into a cache or session variable instead?

If you are looking at large view state problems, you could always try this: http://theoldsewingfactory.com/2008/11/21/a-better-way-to-deal-with-viewstate/